# Are there any web sites that connect language learners for conversation practice?

Tags: resource-request, online-learning

I am currently learning Spanish and my teacher has told me that one of the best ways to learn the language is to participate, talk as much as possible, and to commit errors. I have looked online for a simple way to do this, but have not been able to thus far. Duolingo is simply vocab, and other sites are just not what I am looking for.

Are there any web sites that connect language learners with native speakers for the purpose of conversation practice?

Comment: Note to all: I have created the following question on Meta: [Community wiki for “Websites that allow communication between people: List”?](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/419/800).

Comment: I have edited your question slightly to clarify that you're looking specifically for resources for language conversation practice (otherwise even sites like Grindr would answer your question). I've also removed the request for a list, which makes the question too broad, and narrowed it simply to ask simply for one such site. You may still get multiple answers, and can select your favorite to accept. But this makes the focus of the question more appropriately narrow.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [italki](https://www.italki.com/). You have a lot of options there, from typical language exchange to paid tuition with professional language teachers. And the latter is relatively cheap, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

I found that [verbling](https://www.verbling.com/find-teachers) and [gospeaky](https://www.gospeaky.com/) are great, with [verbling groups](https://www.verbling.com/community) you can even create your own practice group or join other groups, it will definitely help you to improve your speaking. 
Furthermore, you do not need to pay anything if you want just to practice your speaking with other learners or exchange with other native speakers (for example, if you are a native English speaker, you can exchange with native Spanish speakers, so they will help you to learn Spanish and you will help them to learn English).

Answer (score 1):

I've really been enjoying an app on my iPad called [Tandem](https://www.tandem.net/). I think there is a version for Android too.

Answer (score 1):

Another one is [MyLanguageExchange.com](https://mylanguageexchange.com/), (freemium, very reasonable membership fee), and many Spanish speakers interested to exchange Spanish for English. You can search by using different criteria (online-only, in person, gender, etc).

Also, check meetup.com if there is a Spanish learning group in vicinity.